# Could not resize the activity indicator in iOS 5.0?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In my Universal app, in iPAd part I am resizing the activity indicator...

I want to resize my activity indicator..

But there are really iOS problems 
first here is my code...

```
-(void)startSpinner {

    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];



/*spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray]; */    
        spinner.hidden = NO;


    NSLog(@"Start Spinner");   

    if([self isPad])
 spinner.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2,100, 100);
else
 spinner.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2,50, 50);



     NSLog(@"Dpinner size %f",spinner.frame.size.width);

        [spinner setHidesWhenStopped:YES];


           [self.view addSubview:spinner];
                [self.view bringSubviewToFront:spinner];
        /*1*/       **[spinner setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];**
                [spinner startAnimating];

        }
```

Problem 1:

iOS 5.0 : It is showing me activity indicator but could not resize it.
  Size is not changing in isPAd Method.

iOS 4.3 :
It is giving me Signal Abort Error on changing the color. /*1*/Bolded Line in code to set color.
Here If I remove setColor in iOS 5.0 in **WhiteLargeStyle** it is not showing me in White background.

Here If I use Activity Indicator style like **gray** it is absolutely small in iPAd.works but could not resize.

In iOS 4.3 frame get effects but ios 5.0 frames are not effective...

So, How should I resize the activity indicator...

Comment: Integrated but could nt set Frames, size of the Indicator....any idea..

Comment: So the verdict is that activity indicator is NOT resizeable? Is that the verdict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using custom progress indicators as it will give more flexibility.

I am using **MBProgressHUD** and it's simple and great for me.

You can get it here - 
https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: look at the MBProgress files and try to change it there. if you don't know how I will try to help

Answer (score 64):

Try setting the CGAffineTransform of the activity indicator:

```
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5f, 1.5f);
    activityIndicator.transform = transform;
```

Comment: This worked beautifully and I believe is the best answer. Thanks!

Comment: It bears mentioning that this (obviously) upscales it in a way that is raster based, not vector based, so the resultant quality is quite blurry and poor.

Comment: The closest I've seen. Great answer thank you.

Although it looks a little pixelated

Answer (score 0):

iTry this out in my iPad App and it's working fine in both ios

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(300,75,100,100);
    UIActivityIndicatorView *act = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [act startAnimating];
    act.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;
    //[act sizeToFit];
    act.tag=kActTag;
    mainImage.enabled=TRUE;
    [mainImage addSubview:act];
    [act release]; act=nil;
```

Comment: Sorry Hiren frames are not effective inios 5.0

Comment: @ArpitParekh: i have checked in my simulater and it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Arpit

Color property is available for iOS 5.0 and later.
In iOS4.3 error is expected!

Refer http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html

Thanks