# Spin rate of UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

What is the spin speed of a `UIActivityIndicatorView`?  Specifically, how long does it take to complete one revolution?

**UPDATE:** the reason for asking this is that I want to [create my own activity indicator spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010237/creating-a-custom-uiactivityindicatorview) that's smaller than the normal one.  But I [can't change the size of the normal one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638120/can-i-change-the-size-of-uiactivityindicator), so I'm [making my own](http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=336) via `UIImageView`'s animation options.  I want to be as close to the normal one in behavior, timing, feel, etc. as I can get.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: One point one four five two six seven seconds.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Really? Don't tell me you knew that off the top of your head.

Comment: @Undo: It's a guess.  But I'm probably off by no more than about 25 percent.

Comment: I wonder how many people read this and thought "I'm not sure why he wants to know that, but I am sure that whatever he's thinking of using it for is a bad idea."

Comment: Find some custom implementations that others have made on cocoa controls / github and browse their source to see how they've done it.

Comment: Hey, that's a good reason to know and a good thing to do! (Sorry for the smart-alecky comment before)

Comment: Yep, that is a good reason. I'm not sure what I expected, but it wasn't a good UX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spin rate of the UIActivityIndicatorView is 1.0 as of iOS 6.1.4. This number is an implementation detail and is not guaranteed to remain at this value for future versions of iOS. You can figure this out by accessing the first subview of a UIActivityIndicatorView, which is a UIImageView, and querying its animationDuration property. It looks like UIActivityIndicatorView uses an animated UIImageView under the hood.