# Unable to set / increase the size of UIActivityindicator view

Tags: objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I m trying to set size of `UIActivityindicatorview` using `setframe`. It is able to set *position* but not size of control. is there some other way??

This is relevant code.

```
 UIActivityIndicatorView*  mySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    mySpinner.frame=CGRectMake((375/2)-25,210 , 100, 100);
    mySpinner.color=[UIColor blueColor];
     mySpinner.center =self.view.center;
   mySpinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:mySpinner];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change the size of UIActivityIndicator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638120/can-i-change-the-size-of-uiactivityindicator)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What i did to change the `ActivityIndicator` size in app is:

Just Apply the *Transform* on your activity indicator and *Rescale* it.

Here is the code

```
UIActivityIndicatorView*  mySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
mySpinner.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
mySpinner.color=[UIColor blueColor];
mySpinner.center =self.view.center;
mySpinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[self.view addSubview:mySpinner];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added simple extension to use UIActivityIndicatorView with exact size
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70688204/286361